# Adm-Zip "ERROR TypeError: fss.existsSync is not a function" Angular/Typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, adm-zip

I am writing an angular application. So i want to extract a zip file and I am using this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as AdmZip from 'adm-zip';

@Component({
  selector: 'newcomp',
  templateUrl: './newcomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newcomp.component.css']
})
export class NewcompComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  };

  public xyz() {
    var zip = new AdmZip('/home/nityananda/Pictures/abc.zip');
    console.log("opened");
  };
}
```

But I am getting this error `ERROR TypeError: fss.existsSync is not a function`

Comment: `adm-zip` doesn't seem to be compatible with browsers, it says "for Node.js" in the README

Comment: AdmZip is created for NodeJs. And when you use this library you need to have permissions to write or read files from your machine. But you do not have such an opportunity in the browser for security reason.

Comment: can I use it in a electron application please help. @RomaSkydan.

Comment: yes, how I see you can use  special package for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip-electron